# C: Having a pointer to pointer in main and create an array in other function

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I have code like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void mad(int ***, int, in);

int main(void) {
    int **x;
    int n,m;

    scanf("%d%d",&n,&m);
    mad(x,n,m);
    x[0][0] = 5;
    printf("%d\n",x[0][0]);

    return 0;
}

void mad(int ***x, int n, int m) {
    int i;
    **x = malloc(sizeof(int *));

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        ***(x + i) = malloc(m * sizeof(int));
}
```

This is wrong can someone explain why this is wrong and help me to get it right.

Comment: `**x = malloc(sizeof(int *));` -->  `**x = malloc(sizeof(int *) * n);`

Comment: yeah i forgot n in malloc but again doesnt works

Comment: By wrong you mean that it does not compile? If there are errors, you should provide them in your post.

Comment: The prototype of the function and the function declaration aren't equal, they should. Isn't the compiler giving you any error or warning at all?

Comment: >gcc -o end end.c
end.c: In function 'main':
end.c:10:9: warning: passing argument 1 of 'mad' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
end.c:4:6: note: expected 'int ***' but argument is of type 'int **'
end.c: In function 'mad':
end.c:20:37: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]

Comment: i whant in main to have and int ** and in other function call malloc and make my table and then  in main i can use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a variable which is a pointer to a pointer, so declare it as such:

```
int **x;
```

but if you want another function to assign it a value, you need to pass *a pointer to that variable*, so declare a function as

```
void mad(int ***x,int n, int m);
```

call it with passing a pointer to the variable:

```
mad(&x,m,n);
```

and assign a new value to the dereferenced pointer

```
void mad(int ***x,int n, int m)
{
    *x = malloc(...);
}
```

BTW, the first `malloc` call seems incorrect – you allocate the block of memory big enough to keep a single pointer to `int` while it probably should be `n` pointers to `int`:

```
    *x = malloc(n*sizeof(int *));
```

Then allocate your `n` array's rows, each m `int`s long:

```
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        *(*x + i) = malloc(m*sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 1):

`*x` ìs an pointer to a pointer to an array. `malloc(n * sizeof(int*));` allocates an array of pointers. `*(*x+i)` or `(*x)[i]` is an array. `malloc(m * sizeof(int));` allocates an array. Adapt your code like this:

```
void mad(int ***x, int n, int m){
    int i;

    *x = malloc(n * sizeof(int*));       // allocate memory where x refers to
    for( i=0; i<n; i++ )
      *(*x+i) = malloc(m * sizeof(int)); // similar to (*x)[i] = malloc(m * sizeof(int))
}

mad(&x,n,m);
 // ^
```

Comment: "`*x` ìs an 2dimensional array"  This is not a 2D array, it is a pointer-based, fragmented lookup table.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid all of those inefficient pointer-to-pointer based lookup tables. They are not arrays since they are not allocated in adjacent memory cells.

Allocate a real 2D array instead:

```
void alloc2d ( size_t x, size_t y, int(**ptr)[x][y] )
{
  *ptr = malloc ( sizeof(int[x][y]) );
}

int main (void)
{
  const int x = 5;
  const int y = 3;
  int (*arr_ptr)[x][y];

  alloc2d(x, y, &arr_ptr);

  int (*array2d)[y] = *arr_ptr; // point at 1st element which is an array
  array2d[i][j] = something;

  ...
  free(arr_ptr);
}
```